# WPF Pixel line blurring

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm creating a button style that contains a straight line:

```
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M0,0 L10,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

But instead of a 1px wide line, I always get a 2px wide line:

[image]

**I tried using the following** (both in relation to the parent `Grid` and the `Path` element itself): `UseLayoutRounding="True"`, `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`, `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"`, `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`. None of this helped me and doesn't make the line look normal. Previously, one of the above or a combination of them always helped.

I tried to determine the system DPI value for the window and the value that WPF knows:

```
PresentationSource presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window);                 
double wpfDpi = 96.0 * presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;                 
double currentDpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
```

Both values are the same (120) - the application knows about the scale.

Taget platform: NET Framework 4.5

OS: Windows 10 21H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` to your `Path` object.

This will force a 1 pixel wide line onto exact pixel boundaries, giving you a crisp graphic.

You don't need `UseLayoutRounding` or `SnapsToDevicePixels`.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" 
      StrokeThickness="1" 
      Data="M0,0 L10,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                      
      RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
```

Comment: There is another display problem: https://ibb.co/xXrQRJW. Code: https://pastebin.com/4zfht6V7